# Proof for $f(n) = f(n-1)$ holds only when $n$ is a power of two, where $f(n) = n \mod 1 + n \mod 2 + n \mod 3 + ..... + n \mod n $

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

This problem is from [SPOJ](https://www.spoj.com/problems/OPMODULO/), and we are given  $f(n) = (n \mod 1) + (n \mod 2) + (n \mod 3) + \dots + (n \mod n)$. After coding a brute force solution for small $n$, I'm observing that $f(n) = f(n-1)$ exactly when n is a power of two. Can someone help with constructing a proof of its correctness? or maybe prove this is incorrect?

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A004125

Comment: I think this question, or one very like it, has been asked before...but I can't find it.  In any case, I'll post something below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One direction is fairly straight forward, the other is (I believe) unknown.

It is easy to see that $$  n\pmod k - (n-1)\pmod k =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $k\,\nmid \,n$} \\
1-k, & \text{if $k\,|\,n$}
\end{cases}$$

Summing from $k=1$ to $k=n-1$ gives $$f(n)-f(n-1)=(n-1)-(\sigma_1(n)-n)=2n-1-\sigma_1(n)$$

where, as usual, $\sigma_1(m)$ denotes the sum of the divisors of $m$.

Requiring that $f(n)=f(n-1)$ is then revealed to be the same as requiring that $\sigma_1(n)=2n-1$

Such an $n$ is called [almost perfect](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlmostPerfectNumber.html#:%7E:text=The%20only%20known%20almost%20perfect,(OEIS%20A000079).)

It is easy to see that powers of $2$ are almost perfect.  There are no other examples known, though as far as I know it is unknown whether or not there are other almost perfect numbers.

Comment: The other way has a proof. Could you have been thinking of something else?

Comment: @kyary  do you have a reference?  The link I included states it is an open problem )though of course someone might have settled it recently).

Comment: @kyary  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_perfect_number) is another reference which states that the problem is open.

Comment: hmm... I added my proof below. It seemed correct to me, but will double check.

Comment: could you perhaps look over my proof? I don't think I did anything wrong

Comment: @kyary  I posted a comment to your proof.    I found your proof hard to read (definitely worth learning MathJax !), but in particular your claim that, apart from powers of $2$, we must have $n$ significantly greater than the sum of its divisors, is false.  There are perfect numbers, for example, for which the sum of the proper divisors equals the number ($6$ is the smallest example) and there are *abundant* numbers, like $12$, for which the sum of the proper divisors exceeds the original number.

Comment: Yes, I found where I went wrong in the proof. Thanks for taking the time!